# Rails using Views instead of Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to create a Rails app that will show/utilize our current CRM system data. The thing is - I could just take Rails and use current DB as backend, but the table names and column names are the exact opposite Rails use.

Table names:

```
+-------------+----------------+--------------+
| Resource    | Expected table | Actual table |
+-------------+----------------+--------------+
| Invoice     | invoices       | Invoice      |
| InvoiceItem | invoice_items  | InvItem      |
+-------------+----------------+--------------+
```

Column names:

```
+-------------+-----------------+---------------+
| Property    | Expected column | Actual column |
+-------------+-----------------+---------------+
| ID          | id              | IniId         |
| Invoice ID  | invoice_id      | IniInvId      |
+-------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

I figured I could use Views to:

- Normalize all table names
- Normalize all column names
- Make it possible to not use column aliases
- Make it possible to use scaffolding

But there's a big but:

- Doing it on a database level, Rails will probably not be able to build SQL properly
- App will probably be read-only, unless I don't use Views and create a different DB instead and sync them eventually

Those disadvantages are probably even worse when you compare it to just plain aliasing.

And so I ask - is Rails able to somehow transparently know the id column is in fact id, but is InvId in the database and vice versa? I'm talking about complete abstraction - simple aliases just don't cut it when using joins etc. as you still need to use the actual DB name.

Comment: I think use same database is a problem (if you have to modify some column or add column or add table in your rails app, or if you modify something in your CRM tath modify your database). Your CRM have an API interface?

Comment: No. I mean yes. But no, I need to be able to do the JOINs and stuff. For the time being I need it to be read-only, so I don't need to worry about modifying. The user would not even have write access.

Comment: you know [set_primary_key](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/set_primary_key/class) and [table_name](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/table_name/class)?

Comment: Yes. Thing is, there is like 60 tables and each has approximately 30 columns, all of which use this retarded naming. Views solve that problem for more than Rails, question is, can Rails use views instead of tables.